# Excel if statement shorten down?

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have VBA code written to color cells based on what value is in a different cell. Would it be possible to shorten the following down? I'm new to scripting in VBA and was hoping that if this can be shortened then I could apply it to a bigger file.

```
 Sub RoutingCheck()
   Dim I As Long, r1 As Range, r2 As Range

   For I = 2 To 456
      Set r1 = Range("A" & I)
      Set r2 = Range("B" & I)

    If r1.Value = 94 And r2.Value = " " Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 94 And r2.Value = "" Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 94 And r2.Value = -99 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 94 And r2.Value = -66 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 94 And r2.Value = -77 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 94 And r2.Value = " " Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 94 And r2.Value = "" Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 94 And r2.Value = -99 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 94 And r2.Value = -66 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 94 And r2.Value = -77 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 94 And r2.Value <> "" And r2.Value <> -99 And r2.Value <> -66 And r2.Value <> -77 And r2.Value <> " " Then r1.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    If r1.Value = 94 And r2.Value <> "" And r2.Value <> -99 And r2.Value <> -66 And r2.Value <> -77 And r2.Value <> " " Then r2.Interior.Color = vbGreen

    If r1.Value = 1 And r2.Value = "" Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 1 And r2.Value = -66 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 1 And r2.Value = 0 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 1 And r2.Value = -77 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 1 And r2.Value = "" Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 1 And r2.Value = -66 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 1 And r2.Value = 0 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 1 And r2.Value = -77 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 1 And r2.Value <> "" And r2.Value <> -66 And r2.Value <> -77 And r2.Value <> 0 And r2.Value <> -99 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 1 And r2.Value <> "" And r2.Value <> -66 And r2.Value <> -77 And r2.Value <> 0 And r2.Value <> -99 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 1 And r2.Value = -99 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    If r1.Value = 1 And r2.Value = -99 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbGreen

    If r1.Value = 2 And r2.Value = "" Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 2 And r2.Value = -66 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 2 And r2.Value = 0 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 2 And r2.Value = -77 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 2 And r2.Value = "" Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 2 And r2.Value = -66 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 2 And r2.Value = 0 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 2 And r2.Value = -77 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 2 And r2.Value <> "" And r2.Value <> -66 And r2.Value <> -77 And r2.Value <> 0 And r2.Value <> -99 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 2 And r2.Value <> "" And r2.Value <> -66 And r2.Value <> -77 And r2.Value <> 0 And r2.Value <> -99 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 2 And r2.Value = -99 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    If r1.Value = 2 And r2.Value = -99 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbGreen

    If r1.Value = 3 And r2.Value = "" Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 3 And r2.Value = -66 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 3 And r2.Value = 0 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 3 And r2.Value = -77 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 3 And r2.Value = "" Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 3 And r2.Value = -66 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 3 And r2.Value = 0 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 3 And r2.Value = -77 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 3 And r2.Value <> "" And r2.Value <> -66 And r2.Value <> -77 And r2.Value <> 0 And r2.Value <> -99 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 3 And r2.Value <> "" And r2.Value <> -66 And r2.Value <> -77 And r2.Value <> 0 And r2.Value <> -99 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 3 And r2.Value = -99 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    If r1.Value = 3 And r2.Value = -99 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbGreen

    If r1.Value = 4 And r2.Value = "" Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 4 And r2.Value = -66 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 4 And r2.Value = 0 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 4 And r2.Value = -77 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 4 And r2.Value = "" Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 4 And r2.Value = -66 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 4 And r2.Value = 0 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 4 And r2.Value = -77 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 4 And r2.Value <> "" And r2.Value <> -66 And r2.Value <> -77 And r2.Value <> 0 And r2.Value <> -99 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 4 And r2.Value <> "" And r2.Value <> -66 And r2.Value <> -77 And r2.Value <> 0 And r2.Value <> -99 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 4 And r2.Value = -99 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    If r1.Value = 4 And r2.Value = -99 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbGreen

    If r1.Value = 5 And r2.Value = "" Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 5 And r2.Value = -66 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 5 And r2.Value = 0 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 5 And r2.Value = -77 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 5 And r2.Value = "" Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 5 And r2.Value = -66 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 5 And r2.Value = 0 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 5 And r2.Value = -77 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 5 And r2.Value <> "" And r2.Value <> -66 And r2.Value <> -77 And r2.Value <> 0 And r2.Value <> -99 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 5 And r2.Value <> "" And r2.Value <> -66 And r2.Value <> -77 And r2.Value <> 0 And r2.Value <> -99 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 5 And r2.Value = -99 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    If r1.Value = 5 And r2.Value = -99 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbGreen

    If r1.Value = 6 And r2.Value = "" Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 6 And r2.Value = -66 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 6 And r2.Value = 0 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 6 And r2.Value = -77 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 6 And r2.Value = "" Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 6 And r2.Value = -66 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 6 And r2.Value = 0 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 6 And r2.Value = -77 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 6 And r2.Value <> "" And r2.Value <> -66 And r2.Value <> -77 And r2.Value <> 0 And r2.Value <> -99 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 6 And r2.Value <> "" And r2.Value <> -66 And r2.Value <> -77 And r2.Value <> 0 And r2.Value <> -99 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 6 And r2.Value = -99 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    If r1.Value = 6 And r2.Value = -99 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbGreen

    If r1.Value = 7 And r2.Value = "" Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 7 And r2.Value = -66 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 7 And r2.Value = 0 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 7 And r2.Value = -77 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 7 And r2.Value = "" Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 7 And r2.Value = -66 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 7 And r2.Value = 0 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 7 And r2.Value = -77 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 7 And r2.Value <> "" And r2.Value <> -66 And r2.Value <> -77 And r2.Value <> 0 And r2.Value <> -99 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 7 And r2.Value <> "" And r2.Value <> -66 And r2.Value <> -77 And r2.Value <> 0 And r2.Value <> -99 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If r1.Value = 7 And r2.Value = -99 Then r1.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    If r1.Value = 7 And r2.Value = -99 Then r2.Interior.Color = vbGreen

       Next I
       'Error

        End Sub
```

Comment: There are certainly shortcuts you could apply here. You may want to investigate use of the `CASE` command and learn nesting.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the first block, you might do something like this:

```
If r1.Value = 94 Then
   Select case r2.Value
      case " ", "", -99, -66, -77
         r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
         r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
      Case else
         r1.Interior.Color = vbGreen
         r2.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    End Select
ElseIf r1.value = 1 then
   ' repeat the select case or use a function to return the correct colour.
' repeat
End If
```

Your other blocks appear to basically only care if r2 is -99, in which case use green, otherwise red.

Comment: Good answer, also there are some good pointers here : http://www.excelitems.com/2010/12/optimize-vba-code-for-faster-macros.html

Comment: Why not use nested `Select Case`?

Comment: No particular reason other than demonstrating that you don't need to repeat the If test for the same value on every line. I also happen to find this more readable but that's just my preference.

Comment: Thanks for your help although when I run that code it doesn't do anything, what am I missing?

Comment: Yep, I used the following: `Sub RoutingCheck()
   Dim I As Long, r1 As Range, r2 As Range

   For I = 2 To 456
      Set r1 = Range("A" & I)
      Set r2 = Range("B" & I)If r1.Value = 94 Then
   Select case r2.Value
      case " ", "", -99, -66, -77
         r1.Interior.Color = vbRed
         r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
      Case else
         r1.Interior.Color = vbGreen
         r2.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    End Select End If Next I End Sub`

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to format correctly on here yet

Comment: What is in `r1` and `r2`?