# VBA is there anyway to optimize this code?

Tags: vba, optimization

Currently working on something that requires me to use the following code. Just wondering if there is anyway to shorten it down or combine it as such. Any help would be great. And apologies for posting so many questions over the previous few days.

```
Sub RoutingCheck()


   Dim i As Long, c1 As Range, c2 As Range, c3 As Range, c4 As Range

   For i = 2 To 456
      Set c3 = Range("C" & i)
      Set c4 = Range("D" & i)

If c3.Value <> 1 Or c3.Value <> 2 Or c3.Value <> 3 Or c3.Value <> 4 Or c3.Value <> 5 Or c3.Value <> 6 Or c3.Value <> 98 Then c3.Interior.color = vbRed
If c3.Value = 1 Or c3.Value = 2 Or c3.Value = 3 Or c3.Value = 4 Or c3.Value = 5 Or c3.Value = 6 Or c3.Value = 98 Then c3.Interior.color = vbGreen


End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel if statement shorten down?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824236/excel-if-statement-shorten-down)

Comment: Almost, the same question, you stop answering there and didn't accept the answer... And you don't seem to have look for any info on `Select Case` that was suggested there... Just saying...

Comment: Apologies, I thought that the `Select Case` command only worked if it was looking at another column too. My bad. Thanks for the tip though I really appreciate it. Just trying to learn.

Comment: No worries, it's just annoying to see people **asking a lot of questions and not accepting answers...** (so you might want to *accept the useful ones from your profile* ;) ) The learning part is normal, but you'd probably be better with a bit of googling `VBA your issue/method/...` ;) Good luck

Comment: Yeah for a while there i couldn't accept answers because my rep was so low however I can accept now. Thanks for your help I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, so you are confused between accepting and upvoting, see http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Hosey93 if you think of another question with "is there a way to optimize...", "Can anyone shorten...", "Excel if statemeent shorten down" please put it on code review: it does not belong here.  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @tompreston Hi. Yes, ok sorry Tom, just getting to grips with the community and how this all works. Will do in future. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Hosey93 Top guy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what `Select Case` is all about, try the code below :

```
Sub RoutingCheck()

Dim i As Long, c1 As Range, c2 As Range, c3 As Range, c4 As Range

For i = 2 To 456
    Set c3 = Range("C" & i)
    Set c4 = Range("D" & i)

    Select Case c3.Value
        Case 1 To 6
            c3.Interior.Color = vbGreen
        Case Else
            c3.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End Select

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, works great. I tried using the `select case` command but I must have been doing it wrong as it works now.